# Add Fragment to Main Activity android

Tags: java, android

I want to know how to add a fragment in your activity(either by xml(preferably) or java)without crashing your app. I am unable to add it and I've watched many tutorials but could not understand. Every time I add fragment to main activity, my app crashes.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mashh.fragments;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mashh.fragments.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:name="com.example.mashh.fragments.BlankFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />
</LinearLayout>
```

BlankFragment.java

```
package com.example.mashh.fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

}
```

fragment_blank.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mashh.fragments.BlankFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Try to change the activity main layout changing the fragment tag with FrameLayout tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/blank_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:name="com.example.mashh.fragments.BlankFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />
```

xml add `android:id`